# "Unable to match the desired swap behavior" in android studio

Tags: android

So I had created a small project for learning Android Studio in a better way. My Login screen and my "Select your year" (It is a college application) screen had the transitions: Slide in Right -> Slide out left. The screen would slide in from the right and the previous would slide out left and vice versa. After this, I created another transition, for Slide in top -> Slide out bottom. When I applied this XML file to the project, all the transitions throughout the project glitched out. So I deleted them and reverted back to the original changes. But now NOTHING WORKS! All my transitions are glitched out without any reason! The logcat gives me the error:: "Unable to match the desired swap behavior".

I have tried:

1. Clean and Rebuild
2. Apply other transitions
3. Check XML code (never changed it so doesn't matter)
   I really need help this is too annoying!!

Comment: About ```Unable to match the desired swap behavior``` This ans might be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54917041